# Can't select microphone TargetDataLine. Seems, I can use only input that is default for my OS system

Tags: java, audio, audio-recording

I'm trying to read audio input from different microphones. I found very wired behavior. It seems, that whatever microphone I choose, I can grab sound only for microphone that is default for system. I know this, because sum of signals from both 'microphones' is similar, what I hit default system microphone. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class AudioTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException {

        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(8000.0f, 16, 1, true, true);

        // list all microphones
        List<Line.Info> micList = enumerateMicrophones();

        // assign microphone1
        TargetDataLine microphone1 = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(micList.get(1));
        
        // assign microphone2
        TargetDataLine microphone2 = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(micList.get(2));
        
        // read sound from microphone1
        byte[] data1 = new byte[1000];
        microphone1.open(format);
        microphone1.start();
        microphone1.read(data1, 0, 1000);

        // read sound from microphone2
        byte[] data2 = new byte[1000];
        microphone2.open(format);
        microphone2.start();
        microphone2.read(data2, 0, 1000);

        // Print sum (bigger for laud sounds). 
        // Similar values means - both microphones are in fact the same     
        System.out.println("Mic1: " + calcSum(data1));
        System.out.println("Mic2: " + calcSum(data2));
    }
    
    static long calcSum(byte[] data) {
        long sum = 0;
        for(byte bt: data) {
            sum += Math.abs(bt);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static List<Line.Info> enumerateMicrophones() {
        List<Line.Info> out = new LinkedList<Line.Info>();
        Mixer.Info[] mixerInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        for (Mixer.Info info : mixerInfos) {
            Mixer m = AudioSystem.getMixer(info);
            Line.Info[] lineInfos = m.getTargetLineInfo();
            for (Info lineInfo : lineInfos) {
                if (lineInfo.getLineClass().equals(TargetDataLine.class)) {
                    out.add(lineInfo);
                    System.out.println("Mixer: " + info.toString() + "          Line: " + lineInfo.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

}
```

The mixers/lines printed are:

> `Mixer: PulseAudio Mixer, version 0.02          Line: interface TargetDataLine supporting 42 audio formats, and buffers of 0 to 1000000 bytes`
>
> `Mixer: default [default], version 4.15.0-108-generic          Line: interface TargetDataLine supporting 512 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes`
>
> `Mixer: PCH [plughw:0,0], version 4.15.0-108-generic          Line: interface TargetDataLine supporting 24 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes`

Sometimes I have one more device:

> `Mixer: Device [plughw:1,0], version 4.15.0-108-generic          Line: interface TargetDataLine supporting 4 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes`

Sometimes not. Wired

What my operating system Ubuntu sees:

> `#arecord -l`
>
> `**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****`
>
> `card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]`
>
> `Subdevices: 1/1`
>
> `Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`
>
> `card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]`
>
> `Subdevices: 1/1`
>
> `Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`

I have one microphone connected by USB, and one build into laptop.

Comment: Can you also show the names assigned to the microphones that you are comparing?

Comment: @PhilFreihofner - I added to the main post println output as well as microphones list form Ubuntu system (arecord -l). I hope, it helps